# Hide columns from a table in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my index view of a resource I have a table over multiple columns. The table rows get filled via each-do method. Id like to hide columns from the table to view only one column, so that I can easily mark all rows to copy them. Should I just setup a link to a new page on my resource (produce a new action and view) or is there another way?

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. `truncate` in database speak means delete all the rows of a table. Not what you're after. You're (I think) looking for a way to hide columns, or only display a subset of all your table's columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass something like :hide => true in your params for the request, then display the columns unless params[:hide].

You could also do it entirely on the client side by using javascript to hide/show divs when clicked.